# Cloudformation when to use getatt, ref, vs ${}

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to figure out the differences between `GetAtt` vs `Ref` vs `${}`.

From what I understand you use `GetAtt` to refer to objects within the same template only and `Ref` can be used to refer to anything?  Plus when would I use `${}`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Ref** can be used for two things:

1. To return the value of a parameter that you passed in via the parameters section of the template.
2. When you ref the logical ID of another resource in your template, Ref returns what you could consider as a default attribute for that type of resource. So using ref for an EC2 instance will return the instance ID, and Ref'ing an s3 bucket resource will return the bucket name. You can look [at the bottom of each CloudFormation resources page in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance-return-values) to see what this value will be.

**GetAtt** is essentially the same as the 2nd function of Ref above, it also returns an attribute of the resource that you created within your resource, but while ref returns only a default attribute, GetAtt allows you to choose from different attributes to return.

For example, GetAtt for an EC2 instance gives you the option to return the AvailabilityZone, PrivateDnsName, PublicDNSName, etc of an instance - whereas Ref will only return the InstanceID. The different attributes you can return are different per resource type. You can also look [at the bottom of each CloudFormation resources page in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance-return-values) to see what attributes you can all return.

**`${}`** is another way to reference parameters passed in through the parameters section of the template.

All of this is in the AWS documentation though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  If I want to reference something outside the template for example get the `arn` I can based on the explanation given use either ref or getaa?

Comment: No, because these functions only work within a template. If the resource has been created already outside of the template then the arn can be found be just viewing the resource in the console and then you could pass it into cloudformation via a parameter

Comment: Re: `${} is another way to reference parameters`. is it _just_ parameters? According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c26c24c59b7): "Write variables as ${MyVarName}. Variables can be template parameter names, resource logical IDs, resource attributes, or a variable in a key-value map."

Comment: You can also use it instead of `GetAtt`: "If you specify resource attributes, such as ${MyInstance.PublicIp}, CloudFormation returns the same values as if you used the Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function."

Answer (score 11):

[CloudFormation Ref and GetAtt cheatsheet](https://theburningmonk.com/cloudformation-ref-and-getatt-cheatsheet/) is a very handy webpage that can be used to quickly reference what you can get via a `Ref` and `GetAtt` for most CloudFormation resources. You can use a `Ref` for a logical resource's default value (including inside a `Sub` using the ${NAME} method) as well as for a parameter of the stack. `GetAtt` is only useful for logical resources of the stack.

Answer (score 2):

This drawing may help clarify the uses:

[image: stacks]

Comment: This is a little misleading. 1) GetAtt can't get "any property of a resource", it can get a very limited set defined by the resource. 2) ${} can be used for the default of a resource as well, not just for a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @JasonWadsworth. Corrected image.